# .NET Maui pushing a new content page from a Toolbar Item

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I've got a toolbar item in the navigationbar of a Maui app.  This is a shell app.  I've got a  toolbar item in the nav bar.  When I touch the Add toolbar item, the click event happens, but nothing happens in the app.  I don't see my CreateUser() page.  Any suggestions in how to view the page are appreciated.

My content page:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ScanAndScoringMauiApp.Pages.UserSearch"
             Title="UserSearch">
    <Shell.TitleView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Button Text="ADD" x:Name="Add" Clicked="Add_Clicked" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="End"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </Shell.TitleView>
```

My Add_Clicked event is various iterations of the code below. I've tried iterations of this without using InvokeOnMainThreadAsync and on and on.

```
private async void Add_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new CreateUser());
    });
}
```

Comment: if its a Shell app why aren't you using Shell navigation?

Comment: Also are you sure your compiler is able to create an instance of CreateUser class?

Comment: Thanks @Jason.  I had missed that.  I put it in via shell nav and it works now.